# Currying and Uncurrying of logical formulas, is $(A \land B) \to C \leftrightarrow (A\to B)\to C$

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

With a truth table its easy to see that the two formulae $A\land B \to C$ and $A \to B \to C$ are not equivalent, for example, if $A = B = C = 0$, than the first evaluates to $1$ and the second to $0$ (because $A \to B$ is truth, and then $(A\to B) \to C$) is false).

But here

[How do I memorize axioms of a Hilbert system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97865/how-do-i-memorize-axioms-of-a-hilbert-system?rq=1)

it is referred to this transformation as currying, and there

http://www.daimi.au.dk/~ko/teaching/pl/curryhoward.pdf

on page 9 it is stated that

- Curry and Uncurry are proofs of
  $$\forall P,Q,R. (P \land Q) \to R \leftrightarrow (P \to Q \to R)$$

So i am confused, when are these expressions equivalent, and if not how can I use them for "uncurrying"?

Comment: Right arrows like $\to$ or $\implies$, etc., are usually [right-associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity#Notation_for_non-associative_operations), that is $A \to B \to C$ means $A \to (B \to C)$, not $(A \to B) \to C$.

Comment: Huh?  C is not equivalent to (A->B).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The devils is hidden in details. Be careful with parenthesis (and conventions about them).

Indeed, it's true that

- Curry and Uncurry are proofs of
  $$\forall P,Q,R. (P \land Q) \to R \leftrightarrow (P \to (Q \to R))$$

Answer (score 5):

I think $P \to Q \to R$ means $P \to (Q \to R)$ but not $(P \to Q) \to R$.

$(A \land B) \to C \leftrightarrow A\to (B\to C)$ is true.